# Create a column with the keys of a dictionary in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dictionary and DataFrame in python:

```
dicti = {'328392': 1, '657728': 2, '913532': 3, '0153G23': 4, '23932Z': 5}
```

| color | num_ID | other |
| --- | --- | --- |
| red | 1 | train |
| green | 3 | car |
| black | 5 | car |

I want to create a new `number` column with the value of the dictionary key, based on its value.

| color | num_ID | other | number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| red | 1 | train | 328392 |
| green | 3 | car | 913532 |
| black | 5 | car | 23932Z |

Comment: Your dictionary is backwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map`, but with a reverse dictionary:

```
df['number'] = df['num_ID'].map({v:k for k,v in dicti.items()})
```

Answer (score 0):

First create a dataframe from the dictionary:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dicti, orient='index').reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'number', 0: 'num_ID'}).
```

Then merge the dictionary with your original dataframe to create the new column.

```
df_original.merge(df)
```